# Druid wildshapes to recon a city from above, how to limit?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, wild-shape

Im running a heavily modified Second Darkness Pathfinder game and we are on the 3rd book with the city battle. One of the players is a druid and has come up with the idea to wild shape and recon the city from high above and as a tiny bird. This was a great idea on his part and Im going to reward him with the desired knowledge as best I can, but currently I have nothing which is really a threat to him while he is doing this. Now, being a large scale battle, the enemy has some divination spells for gathering intel, but I dont have anything to deal with a single shape changed PC flying high over the city. The idea isnt to kill him (unless he's really stubborn). And while I do have some drow on giant bats (arcane casters) I dont feel they would be well suited for this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25104/discussion-on-question-by-fering-druid-wildshapes-to-recon-a-city-from-above-ho).

Comment: Fering, please add clarifications about your actual problem from the comment thread into your question.  As it stands it is not stating any real problem, use the discussion to clarify expressing your exact problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**He accomplished something with his characters abilities. Make it interesting for him!**
What is important is that you see this from the players perspective. They have found a good way to gain advantage on their enemy, which is what large scale battles really benefit from. Let the players enjoy that, don't take it away. But: *don't make it too easy and boring for them* Let the druid succeed with this for some time, no problem. But the enemy will probably realise at some point and try to do something against it. Keep it interesting for the druid, not by trying to kill him or heavily threatening him, but by making his scouts harder. How about a sky race with some big flying animal that tries to eat him, but soon realises he is not that easy prey it was looking for, and let's him continue after some time?

Also, this can be a good start to additional goals for the rest of the party. *Give them something to do, too!* Maybe a summoner noticed the druid and tries to stop him with a swarm of flying creatures? As a tiny bird the druid will have problems fighting (except for maybe casting some spells, if he can cast them while he is a bird) and needs help from his party, who need to find and kill the summoner.

In short: **use it to enhance your story, don't try to prevent it!**

Answer (score 1):

**Limit the Druid's ability to gather information by keeping him in the sky higher above the city, using invisibility, or hiding indoors.**

Assuming that patrols around the city have archers/spell-casters.  In order to gain information about a patrol, require the druid to make a perception check for 1d6 rounds.  Each round allow the patrol a perception check to notice the bird hanging around unusually, and then initiate combat to try and chase/kill him.  If the druid is further away, then the perception test to spot the druid would be harder, but the druid is unable to gather as much information.

Arcane Casters in your city means access to spells such as invisibility/mass invisibility (Depending on level/access to wands etc.)  It's completely feasible to say that there are several patrols or areas who are invisible until attacked.
This way as well if they do attempt to sneak into the city and happen to stumble across an invisible patrol, it changes the odds compared to what they would be expecting and can catch them off guard.  If your druid has access to level 7 spells, he can easily cast True Seeing on himself as a counter, but you don't necessarily have to advertise the invisible patrols.

It's a city battle, and cities have buildings.  It's entirely possible that patrols are simply indoors while he passes by.  Any bird flying indoors would be instantly suspicious, and perhaps harder to escape from as well.

Using this information should definitely allow the druid to get an advantage from his creative thinking, while preventing him from sticking around and finding out every little detail, while still giving you a chance to surprise the party with unexpected encounters as well.

Answer (score 1):

If it is known by the city's defenders that the ability to transform into birds (or look through their eyes) exists and that there's a reasonable chance that the attacker has that ability, there's a good chance they will deploy Falconers to make it more dangerous to scout the city.

This provides the Druid with an obstacle, although not a very dangerous one (even in animal form, he has considerable combat power, much more than a common falcon, owl or eagle). But it will definately limit his ability to scout around freely.

Also, once people know that aerial scouting is a thing, important information will move indoors. Lots of soldiers will spend much of their time inside while not on active duty to hide numbers.

As a final note; your city can still be fluid. If your druid takes an hour to scout then by the time he is back and has shared the gathered intel, a *lot* of the information is already outdated again. That fight he spotted at the start of his run is already over, the troop movements have been completed, the high value target has regrouped with his bodyguards, etc.

You can still roll random dice and keep the city fluid due to how quickly the situation can change. Just reward him by maybe removing some of the nastier options from the random table, or maybe let him influence the roll with his scouting results.

Answer (score -3):

## Don't let him fly freely.

For example, the city is protected by a magical barrier that doesn't allow him to actually fly *into* the city. Or, as soon as the people in the city get air of him, put up some resistances. Not necessarily to kill him, but scare him away. This way, you only have to plan a part of the city, namely the reduced information they manage to gather, instead of everything.

The downside of scouting is that it's extremely dangerous for the scout. You may have your party feel that threat, so they'll be more careful with sending out a scout next time.

Comment: Shutting down players who use their abilities creatively tends to have the negative side effect of discouraging players from creative problem solving, and reduces player agency in your game. Do you have any suggestions on how to avoid these side effects?

Comment: @GMJoe You don't shut it down completely. The city had accounted for this, and prepared to encounter any scouts. However, if the party is careful, they can still gather some information, just not all of it, which seemed to be the DM's problem.